# change icon sizes in Gtk+ 3 applications

Tags: gtk3

Using `Gtk+ 2`, I could use the `gtk-icon-sizes` option like this:

```
gtk-icon-sizes = panel-menu=32,32:panel=32,32:gtk-menu=32,32:gtk-large-toolbar=64,64:gtk-small-toolbar=48,48:gtk-button=32,32
```

`gtk-icon-sizes` was deprecated and removed in `Gtk+ 3`.

How do I change icon sizes in `Gtk+ 3`?

Answer (score 4):

It's not great news for you, but from the [Arch Linux forum](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=171664), it seems gtk dev have decided to take it out and not replace it:

> GTK+ 3.10 intentionally doesn't pay attention to "gtk-icon-sizes" because the current developers want it to have less "obscure" options like this.  I have talked with them about it on IRC and unfortunately they aren't likely to change their minds.